# Xampp slow response with WIZ107

Tags: apache, http, server, xampp, atmega

I want to send data from an Atmega32 to a Laravel site, for this i got a WIZ107 convertor which is set to auto connect to the Laravel site on port 80.
Atmega--(HTTP)-->WIZ107--(HTTP)-->Server

The problem is the slow response time from server, almost all the time is 5 seconds. Accessed from the browser the delay is no more. I am running on XAMPP v3.2.2

How can I get rid of this delay?

This is the function which sends the HTTP request

```
void http_send_get(char *code, char *code_source, char *turnistle_id)
{
usart_putstring("GET ");
usart_putstring(HTTP_SERVER_PHP_SCRIPT_LOCATION);
usart_putstring("?code=");
usart_putstring(code);
usart_putstring("&source=");
usart_putstring(code_source);
usart_putstring("&turnistle_id=");
usart_putstring(turnistle_id);

usart_putstring(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
usart_putstring("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.8\r\n");
usart_putstring("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n");
usart_putstring("Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2\r\n");
usart_putstring("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
usart_putstring("Host: 192.168.1.7\r\n");
usart_putstring("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n");
usart_putstring("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0\")\r\n");
usart_putstring("\r\n");
usart_putc(0x10);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, is this really PHP code? Reference is `&`, variables must start with `$`, functions does not have return type specified, must start with `function`... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is C code. It just shows how the HTTP request is made. Variables code, code_source and turnistle_id are strings and HTTP_SERVER_PHP_SCRIPT_LOCATION is a string which tells the resource on server. It is set to "/check".
My problem is the server slow response when I send the request by uC. Accessed from the browser is really fast.

Comment: So if it's `C` code, why question tagged as PHP?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Tag removed